# UIScrollView with images and memory management

Tags: ios, image, caching, memory

I have a UIScrollView with a lot of large images. I followed the steps on [WWDC 2010 Video: Designing Apps with Scrolls Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) and I thought that their memory management methods wouldn't require any cache setup. I developed an Android app before this and I needed to implement a cache to store images. Is this the case in iOS too?

P.S. - The app just closes after I've scrolled upto a certain number of images. Which obviously seems to be a threshold.

Comment: Can you post some code for creating your UIScrollView?  Also is there any reason not to use a UITableView instead since it will automatically release cells that are not visible.

Comment: Well I've created my scrollview to show one image at a time. It's similar to the iOS photo app, except that I load the images from the internet. Otherwise the implementation matches the one in the link I've mentioned above.